# Tkinter checkbutton bind does not take the updated value

Tags: validation, checkbox, tkinter, bind

I have defined two checkbutton labels: (var is the class I use so that I have access to the variables outside as well)

```
lby = ttk.Checkbutton(var.frame,text="y-direction",variable=var.vel_y)
lbz = ttk.Checkbutton(var.frame,text="z-direction",variable=var.vel_z)
lby.grid(column=1,row=3,sticky=W)
lbz.grid(column=1,row=4,sticky=W)
```

Now, I bind the user-click on any of the buttons to call a function options_yz().

```
 def options_yz(key):
    print("y"+str(var.vel_y.get()))
    print("z"+str(var.vel_z.get()))
 lby.bind('<Button-1>', options_yz)
 lbz.bind('<Button-1>', options_yz)
```

But it seems to me that the button-click calls the function before changing the value of the variable. Is there any way to call the function after changing the variable?

For example:
The default values for var.vel_y and var.vel_z are 0. I click on the checkbutton for y-direction. My output is:

```
y0
z0
```

My actual output should be:

```
y1
z0
```

Next I click on the checkbutton for z-direction. My output is:

```
y1
z0
```

My actual output should be:

```
y1
z1
```

Comment: Take a look on `trace()` function on tkinter variables.

Comment: Perfect! That works like a charm! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why are you using `bind` rather than the `command` attribute of the checkbutton?

Comment: That works too. I am quite new with tkinter, so I am not very familiar with all the common functionalities :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by acw1668, instead of binding the function to user-click on the buttons, I bind it to the user-change of the variables. So my code is changed to:

```
def options_yz(*args):
    print("y"+str(var.vel_y.get()))
    print("z"+str(var.vel_z.get()))
var.vel_y.trace("w", options_yz)
var.vel_z.trace("w", options_yz)
```

And it does exactly what I need!